# How can I make SMTP authenticated in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, smtp

I create new ASP.NET web application that use SMTP to send message. The problem is the smtp was not authenticated from who send the message.

How can I make SMTP authenticated in my program? does C# have a class that have attribute for enter username and password?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

using(SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
{
    var basicCredential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password"); 
    using(MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
    {
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@yourdomain.com"); 

        smtpClient.Host = "mail.mydomain.com";
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = basicCredential;

        message.From = fromAddress;
        message.Subject = "your subject";
        // Set IsBodyHtml to true means you can send HTML email.
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = "<h1>your message body</h1>";
        message.To.Add("to@anydomain.com"); 

        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //Error, could not send the message
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

You may use the above code.

Comment: where is the username and password coming from ? and what is mail.mydomain.com ? is that he DNS name ?

Comment: they're your email address and password, mail.mydomain.com is your SMTP server (e.g. smtp.gmail.com).

Comment: You should you wrap the MailMessage object in a using statement (or call Dispose on it after your done), right?

Comment: Usually you'll also need to configure a port. This can be done by using the [Port Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.port?view=netframework-4.8) like `smtpClient.Port(123)`

Comment: @Arief: Hi can you check my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604850/problem-in-sending-email-via-smtp-service-not-as-external-senders    any suggestion about how to make our send mail function, not as external senders?

Answer (score 91):

Ensure you set `SmtpClient.Credentials` **after** calling `SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false`.

The order is important as setting `SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false` will reset `SmtpClient.Credentials` to null.

Comment: When using Sendgrid and the order is wrong - it will return error: "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Unauthenticated senders not allowed". Setting Credentials after the UseDefaultCredentials flag fixes this problem

Comment: based on the implementation, you don't even need to set `UseDefaultCredentials` if you are already setting `Credentials` since they are both based on the same underlying value.

Answer (score 7):

Set the [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.credentials.aspx) property before sending the message.

Answer (score 3):

To send a message through TLS/SSL, you need to set Ssl of the SmtpClient class to true.

```
string to = "jane@contoso.com";
string from = "ben@contoso.com";
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Subject = "Using the new SMTP client.";
message.Body = @"Using this new feature, you can send an e-mail message from an application very easily.";
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
// Credentials are necessary if the server requires the client 
// to authenticate before it will send e-mail on the client's behalf.
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(message);
```

Comment: write some code example about SSL vs SMTP Client to make better answer

Answer (score 1):

How do you send the message?

The classes in the `System.Net.Mail` namespace (which is probably what you should use) has full support for authentication, either specified in Web.config, or using the `SmtpClient.Credentials` property.

Answer (score 0):

In my case even after following all of the above. I had to upgrade my project from .net 3.5 to .net 4 to authorize against our internal exchange 2010 mail server.

Answer (score 0):

Add `MailKit` through NuGet Package Manager, then use the following code:

```
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit.Security;
using MimeKit;
using MimeKit.Text;

using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
{
    using (MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage())
    {
        try
        {
            var email = new MimeMessage();
            email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(@"<sender email>"));
            email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("<recipient email>"));
            email.Subject = "<subject here>";
            email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html) { Text = "<h1>your message body</h1>" };
            var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            await smtp.ConnectAsync("smtp.<provider>.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
            await smtp.AuthenticateAsync(@"<sender email>", @"<password>");
            await smtp.SendAsync(email);
            await smtp.DisconnectAsync(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Error, could not send the message
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

The method `smtp.AuthenticateAsync(user, password)` is where you pass a username/email and a password/key

Replace the values in angle brackets with the suitable values from your side