# I'm having problems with SMTP Authentication in C#

Tags: c#, smtp

I have an MVC 3 app and everything I try on my new hosting provider ends up throwing this exception:

**Server Error in '/' Application.
Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Authentication is required for relay**

I tried using the code from

[How can I make SMTP authenticated in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298363/how-can-i-make-smtp-authenticated-in-c-sharp)

which has many up votes, but I still get the exception.

My host has the typical panels that let me create mail accounts. I'm not sure about creating NetworkCredentials, what do I use as the User Name and password? What I've been using is the email address and the password for the email account.

Here's my code:

```
public static void sendMail(Joiner request) {
  SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
  NetworkCredential basicCredential =
      new NetworkCredential("garbage@stopthedumpcoalition.org", "REDACTED");
  MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
  MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("garbage@stopthedumpcoalition.org");

  smtpClient.Host = "mail.stopthedumpcoalition.org";
  smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
  smtpClient.Credentials = basicCredential;

  message.From = fromAddress;
  message.Subject = "Join the Coalition request from - " + request.FirstName + " " + request.LastName;
  //Set IsBodyHtml to true means you can send HTML email.
  message.IsBodyHtml = true;
  message.Body = "Name: " + request.FirstName + " " + request.LastName + "<br>"
        + "EMail: " + request.Email + "<br>"
        + "Wants to Volunteer: " + request.Volunteer.ToString() + "<br>"
        + "Organization: " + request.Organization + "<br>"
        + "Wants to become a Partner: " + request.Partner.ToString() + "<br>"
        + "Comments: " + request.Comments;
  message.To.Add("nivram509@gmail.com");

  smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: Couldn't it simply be that the username is `garbage` and not `garbage@stopthedumpcoalition.org`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sani. It was even stupider than that. My Site Host's web panel had two text boxes for changing the password, I I filled both out and hit save.

It also had a checkbox for "change Password" and I never noticed it.

So I had the wrong password. The code is fine. :)