# WebMatrix Not sending mail now that it is moved to the server

Tags: c#, email, razor, webmatrix, webmail

I am trying to get WebMatrix running on a local server (simply for testing within our intranet), but it is having trouble sending mail where it never did before on my local (work) machine.

I am getting a simple, the operation has timed out message. The account for this is setup through gmail, so I wouldn't think that there would be too many problems, but as I have never set up WebMatrix on a server before, I don't really know how to attack this issue.

When I had the Email working in construction of this website, I used these settings and everything worked fine:

```
WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
WebMail.EnableSsl = false;
```

Then when I ran it with these settings on the server I got this error:

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.  The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.
```

With that, we tried to enable SSL, but get a simple response timed out request after that (using these settings):

```
WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
WebMail.SmtpPort = 465;
WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
```

The "Username" and "From" fields are set the same (name@somecity.net) this is an example of our email that is managed by gmail.  Also the password is set and correct.

Am I chasing the wrong thing here, by looking into SSL?

You'll have to forgive me in that I have never implemented SSL before.  I know what SSL is, but I have never set it up before, so I apologize if I am a kind of a noob when it comes to setting this up.

Also, just so you know for sure, the server error does, in fact, error on the WebMail.Send method.

Comment: what message is displaying with `telnet yourIPserver 465` on command prompt ?

Comment: Sure, just type `telnet yourIPserver 465` in CMD and tell me the response. Should be something like this: 
`220 test.auto.mySMTPserver.com ESMTP Service (Lotus Domino Release 8.5.3FP2 HF95)
 ready at Tue, 30 Oct 2012 08:27:31 -0700`

Comment: @BrOSs 'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: @BrOSs That's what it says when I type it in

Comment: @BrOSs Also, I'm not sure what you mean by yourIPserver. You don't mean "smtp.gmail.com" do you?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that you had Telnet Service available.. you could enable telnet [here](http://www.askdrtech.com/solutions/post/How-to-Enable-Telnet-Client-on-Windows-7.aspx) (if you are running windows 7). About the command, is pretty straight-fwd. With yourIPserver I meant the host machine where your SMTP server is.

Comment: @BrOSs So you mean "smtp.gmail.com"? Isn't that the smtp server I am trying to use.  The account that is setup for this uses something like this "someName@oklecity.net" which is managed through gmail.

Comment: Yeah, if Google is handling your server try `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465` so.. Anyway, I think gmail is working with port 587 instead.

Comment: @BrOSs Really? We looked this port up yesterday (my boss knew where to go) but, perhaps the info was outdated?

Comment: Well, some weeks ago I used the gmail smtp services for a web application for intranet proposes. It worked out fine.

Comment: @BrOSs Well, when I telneted on port 465 the cmd prompt went blank.  When I telneted on 587, it says this:  220 mx.google.com ESMTP nd14sm926849obb.14

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18804/discussion-between-bross-and-voidking)

Comment: King, what if we move this conversation to another place? "Please avoid extended discussions in comments" damn.. the chatroom is firewalled where I'm working right now. mailme: brossdmg at gmail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your *SMTP port* for the Gmail one. Right now, gmail is working with *587* instead of *465*.

You can check it using `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`. Then you should get something like this:

`220 test.auto.mySMTPserver.com ESMTP Service (Lotus Domino Release 8.5.3FP2 HF95) ready at Tue, 30 Oct 2012 08:27:31 -0700`

Your new code:

```
WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the message tells you you are not authenticated, so you are likely to need to send a username / password for a valid user on the server.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298363/how-can-i-make-smtp-authenticated-in-c-sharp) for an example of authenticating to a mail server to send.

Comment: But isn't that what WebMail.UserName, WebMail.Password, and WebMail.From is for?  All of those are set...

Comment: I need to do this is WebMatrix which is slightly different than raw C#.  I mean I know that I can write simple .cs files in WebMatrix, but I wouldn't know when and under what circumstances to call them in this case, as I am a noob at this 'setting up ssl and email' stuff