# Integrate with Exchange Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, exchange-server, contacts

I am developing the web application using asp.net 4.0. And I have requirement to integrate with Outlook user log in. My web application users need to enter their Outlook email and password. How I check entered outlook email and password is validate email address or not.

Is there any API for that or nay other way to do validate email address?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use SMTP, see this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298363/how-can-i-make-smtp-authenticated-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Adil- thank for your help. bot i do not want send mail.. I want to validate user entered email and password correct or not.... and i need only validate user login.

Comment: Outlook users normally uses Active Directory to maintain email addresses and passwords and generally outlook username and passwords are same as windows username and password. Do you have the similar infrastructure?

Comment: @KiranVarsani : Thanks for ur reply. I do not have the similar infrastructure and that is the issue.. And our users are in global.  Only common id is outlook email..

Comment: What kind of email server do you use? I mean Microsoft exchange server etc. If you use exchange server then I guess it should have some kind of API you may be able to use. This is a reference link regarding what I am talking about. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: We have exchange server.

Comment: Then you want to integrate and check Exchange Server's Contatcs and Address Books, not Outlook's.

Comment: Actualy i want to validate login  email and password.. thats only..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can validate the email address and password for Exchange Server account using

1. EWS (Exchange Web Service) [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220499(v=exchg.80).aspx). It is open source and also hosted on [Github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api). See these questions on SO, tagged with [ews-managed-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ews-managed-api). If you only want to authenticate, then it should be the ideal choice.
2. 3rd party library that supports connecting to Exchange Server e.g. [Aspose.Email](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/emailnet/Get+Mailbox+Information+from+Exchange+Server).